# Setting URL gif background but not working with new frame on Python 2

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to create a program with main frame and three buttons that opens new frame. I was able to get URL .gif image as background for main frame but I'm having difficulty changing URL .gif image for new frame when it is loaded.
I been trying to figure it out but there is not much information regarding new frame window with URL .gif background. Can any one give me a hand? Thank you

```
from Tkinter import*
import urllib
import base64
import Tkinter


def epl_Window():
    epl = Tk()
    epl.title("E")
    URL = "h"
    epl.a = urllib.urlopen(URL)
    raw_input = epl.a.read()
    epl.a.close()
    c = base64.encodestring(raw_input)
    image = PhotoImage(data=c)
    label = Label(image=image)
    label.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not work for 2 reasons related to `epl_Window()` method:

- You are running more than one instance of `Tk()`
- You did not attach `label` to `epl`

## Solution

You can fix those 2 problems respectively by:

- Using [`Toplevel()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) to change  the line `epl = Tk()` to `epl = Tkinter.Toplevel()`
- Changing `label = Label(image = image)` to `label = Label(epl, image = image)`

## Demo

Once you apply the modifications above, you will get this (I clicked on the 3 buttons):

[image]

## Bonus

- Follow the standards by running `import Tkinter as Tk`
- Respect this way of instantiating your widgets: `label = Tk.Label(...)`
- Apply object-oriented concepts
- Follow [**PEP**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/)s

Comment: Yea Toplevel() fixed it, Thanks